# expo-location does not work correctly to save all positions in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

I use expo-location in my react-native app to track all positions of the user. I save the positions in redux object and when i debug the object i find all my positions were inserted, but when i recuperate this array i find an empty array:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import MapView, { Polyline, Marker } from 'react-native-maps';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Monitor from './Monitor';
import * as turf from '@turf/turf';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import Pin from './Pin';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { addPosition, positionsData } from '../../reduxThings/positionSlice';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';



const Run = ({distance, latitude, longitude}) => {
    const mapRef = useRef(null);
    const [stateDistance, setStateDistance] = useState(0);
    const [statePace, setStatePace] = useState(0);
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);
    const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState({coords: {latitude, longitude}});
    const positions = useSelector(positionsData);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    console.log(positions);

  
    const onNewPosition = (position) => {
        mapRef?.current?.animateToRegion(position.coords, 1000);
        const durr = positions.length>0 ? position.timestamp - positions[0].timestamp : 0;
        const dist = positions.length>0 ?distanceBetween(positions[positions.length - 1], position):0;
        const pace = positions.length>0 ?paceBetween(dist, positions[positions.length - 1], position):0;

        setCurrentPosition(position);
        setDuration(durr);
        dispatch(addPosition(position));
        setStateDistance(dist);
        setStatePace(pace);
        setCoordinates([...coordinates, {"latitude": position.coords.latitude, "longitude": position.coords.longitude}]);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        const options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeInterval: 1000, distanceInterval: 0 };
        let locations = await Location.watchPositionAsync(options,onNewPosition);
      })();
    }, []); 
    

      const distanceBetween = (origin, destination) => {
        const from = turf.point([origin.coords.longitude, origin.coords.latitude]);
        const to = turf.point([destination.coords.longitude, destination.coords.latitude]);
        const options = {units: 'meters'};
         
        return Math .round(turf.distance(from, to, options));
      }

      const paceBetween = (del, pp, p) =>{
        const time = (p.timestamp - pp.timestamp);
        return time / del;
      }
      
  return (
    <View style ={styles.container}>
        <Monitor distance={stateDistance} pace={statePace}/>
        <MapView 
          ref={mapRef}
    
        initialRegion={{latitude, longitude, latitudeDelta: 0.001, longitudeDelta:0.01}}
        provider="google" style={styles.map}>
            <Marker  coordinate={currentPosition.coords}>
                <Pin/>
                </Marker>
            <Polyline coordinates={coordinates} strokeColor="#f2b659" strokeWidth={10}/>
        </MapView>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Run

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
      },
    map: {
        flex: 1,
      },
})
```

```
On my onNewPosition positions is always empty.
this is my redux code:

import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const positionSlice = createSlice({
    name: "position",
    initialState: {
        positions: []
    },
    reducers: {
        addPosition: (state, action) => {
             
            state.positions = [...state.positions, action.payload];
            console.log(state.positions);
        } 
    }
})

export const { addPosition } = positionSlice.actions;
export const positionsData = (state) => state.position.positions;
export default positionSlice.reducer;
```

any help please?

I tried a local state also and i had the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is a stale closure over the selected `positions` state array in the `onNewPosition` callback handler. `onNewPosition` is instantiated on the initial component render and passed as a callback to the `Location.watchPositionAsync` function in the `useEffect`. This is done only once since the `useEffect` hook has an empty dependency array.

### Use a React Ref to cache state

I'd suggest caching the selected `positions` array in a React ref that can be accessed in the callback handler.

Example:

```js
const Run = ({ distance, latitude, longitude }) => {
  ...

  const positions = useSelector(positionsData);
  const positionsRef = React.useRef(positions);

  // Update ref when positions updates
  useEffect(() => {
    positionsRef.current = positions;
  }, [positions]);

  ...

  const onNewPosition = (position) => {
    mapRef?.current?.animateToRegion(position.coords, 1000);

    // Access current positions from ref
    const positions = positionsRef.current;

    const durr = positions.length ? position.timestamp - positions[0].timestamp : 0;
    const dist = positions.length
      ? distanceBetween(positions[positions.length - 1], position)
      : 0;
    const pace = positions.length
      ? paceBetween(dist, positions[positions.length - 1], position)
      : 0;

    setCurrentPosition(position);
    setDuration(durr);
    dispatch(addPosition(position));
    setStateDistance(dist);
    setStatePace(pace);
    setCoordinates(coordinates => [
      ...coordinates,
      {
        "latitude": position.coords.latitude,
        "longitude": position.coords.longitude
      }
    ]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeInterval: 1000,
        distanceInterval: 0
      };
      const locations = await Location.watchPositionAsync(options, onNewPosition);
    })();
  }, []); 
    
  ...
      
  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

### Access the state from the store object

An alternative is to import the `store` object and access directly the current state value.

Example:

```js
import { store } from '../path/to/store';

...

const Run = ({ distance, latitude, longitude }) => {
  ...

  const onNewPosition = (position) => {
    mapRef?.current?.animateToRegion(position.coords, 1000);

    // Access current positions state from store
    const positions = positionsData(store.getState());

    const durr = positions.length ? position.timestamp - positions[0].timestamp : 0;
    const dist = positions.length
      ? distanceBetween(positions[positions.length - 1], position)
      : 0;
    const pace = positions.length
      ? paceBetween(dist, positions[positions.length - 1], position)
      : 0;

    setCurrentPosition(position);
    setDuration(durr);
    dispatch(addPosition(position));
    setStateDistance(dist);
    setStatePace(pace);
    setCoordinates(coordinates => [
      ...coordinates,
      {
        "latitude": position.coords.latitude,
        "longitude": position.coords.longitude
      }
    ]);
  }

  ...
      
  return (
    ...
  );
};
```